# Unable to locate jenkins.xml file within executable directory or any parents

Tags: windows, jenkins

I've installed jenkins on windows, and I wanted to use jenkins command to start and stop the program from anywhere in the system.

It turns out that after configuring jenkins and creating the environment variable I get the error below everytime I execute "jenkins start" from outside C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins.

Is there any configuration missing?

**ERROR**

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate jenkins.xml file within executable directory or any parents
   at winsw.ServiceDescriptor..ctor()
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)
```

**SYSTEM ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**

JENKINS_HOME:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\jenkins

Path:

- %JENKINS_HOME%

Comment: Did you try and find *jenkins.xml*?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your jenkins install jenkins.xml at the place where is your jenkins.xml

```
1 rename winsw.exe to jenkins.exe
2 cd c:/...where is your jenkins.exe
3 run jenkins.exe install jenkins.xml (both files must be in the same directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, the path of the configuration file (config.xml) is:
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins

The Folder ProgramData is hidden, so go to the address bar and type or use the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Save your jenkins-agent file as xml format. not just jenkins-agent.xml

we can use notepad++ to save the xml type. similarly remove .exe at end of jenkins-agent.exe

Hope its useful.... cheers !!